# How to get subarray values in PHP and insert to Mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

below is my current output which is generated using `var_dump()`, it contains four subarrays, look at the output below

```
array (size=4)
0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'id' => string '11' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'id' => string '10' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'id' => string '12' (length=2)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'id' => string '9' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'id' => string '7' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'id' => string '8' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'id' => string '13' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'id' => string '14' (length=2)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'id' => string '5' (length=1)
```

I want to get the id numbers from all sub arrays based on the array and insert to the following Mysql table,

```
groups { groupName, Idnumber};
```

for example the id 13, 14 and 5 are found in array index 3, then it would be inserted to the table groups like

```
groups { group3, 13,
         group3, 14},
         group3, 5};
```

Comment: Two nested foreach loops, append index of the outer loop to `group`, and then insert that and the id value into your database ...

Comment: @CBroe can you please give a little detailed explanation?

Comment: I used a `foreach` loop nested under two `for` loops but the output is repetitive as much as the number of the outer `for` loop value

Comment: You got two array dimensions here, so why would you use _three_ loops?